# How to assemble the html pages in Play! framework?

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I try to divide every page into header, body and footer.
In html files, I just need to use "@" following the files I need to import to assemble the pages. However, I want to realize it in scala method:

```
class Page {
  private val header = new Header
  private val body = new Body
  private val footer = new Footer
  def getPage():Html = header.getHeader+body.getBody+footer.getFooter
}
```

As we know, "+" is the method for String type, not for Html. How will I realize it like  "@" goes?

Comment: It seems like it would make more sense to do this in a view. Is there any reason why you are determined to do it in code?

Comment: well i need to do it for well-maintaining. is there any method to append a templete files in the end of another one?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do view views as @tryx mentioned.

A simple example: make index.scala.html with this content:

```
@()

@header
@body
@footer
```

Create header.scala.html, body.scala.html, footer.scala.html with any content you want. They must be in "views" folder of your play project. It should contain example views there by default for you to start. Use it with this code in your request handler:

```
def index = { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index)
}
```

Alternatively if you want to form body in code you may do it like this in your index.scala.html:

```
@(content: Html)

@header
@content
@footer
```

And use it like this:

```
def index = { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.index(myBodyInHTMLString))
}
```